# Relation between back emf and flux linkage

Tags: dc-motor, back-emf

I've encountered a problem when trying to figure out my Electric Machine homework. In the homework's answer, it said that the back emf of a DC motor is equal to the speed of the motor times the flux linkage(Eb = N*Φ), which made me very confused. Based on my knowledge, I thought that the back emf is supposed to be calculated by the derivative of the flux linkage with respect to time. So I want to know how this equation is derived?
[image: here is the answer screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula can be easily derived from certain considerations.

First of all we are concerned with average emf generated. so we consider one rotation of a conductor.

in that one complete rotation average flux in our conductor will be Poles × flux.

Also time taken for one rotation = 60\N where N is in rpm.

so average emf generated in one rotation = (poles ×flux)(60\N) so rearranging you can see average emf per conductor in single rotation being proportional to flux and N. so constant parameters are bit different. You only need this fact while solving most problems in DC machine.

Comment: Then why this answer still correct if we didn't multiply the constant parameter? or in this case the constant is already multiplied into the flux linkage?

Comment: There is definitely constant parameters in front of flux and N. you gotta check out other sources for correct information.